# Arguments of solutions to $2\pi i+\log z^6=6\log z$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ be such that
>   $$2\pi i+\log z^6=6\log z$$
>   Determine all the possible values of $\arg z$. Justify your answer.

How do I start this question? Any hints will be most welcome. I tried expanding the log function, but then I have $2\pi i=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $\log(z)$ denotes the principal branch of the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Complex_logarithm), then
$$\log(z)=\log|z|+i\cdot\mbox{arg}(z)$$
where $\mbox{arg}(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$.
Hence your equation becomes
$$2\pi i + 6\log |z|+i\cdot\mbox{arg}(z^6) = 6\log |z|+6i\cdot\mbox{arg}(z)$$
that is
$$2\pi  + \mbox{arg}(z^6) = 6\cdot\mbox{arg}(z).$$
Note that if $z=e^{i\pi/3}$ then
$$2\pi  +\mbox{arg}(e^{6i\pi/3}) = 6\cdot\frac{\pi}{3}\implies 2\pi +0=2\pi.$$
So there is at least one solution. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think that you've made a mistake, because there are no solutions.

Comment: @Jan Eerland If $z=e^{i\pi/3}$ then what are $\mbox{arg}(z)$ and $\mbox{arg}(z^6)$?

Comment: Then $\arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\arg(z^6)=0$

Comment: @Jan Eerland So $z=e^{i\pi/3}$ is a solution.

Comment: @RobertZ i think i can proceed now :)

Comment: @ross999 Good! Don't forget to accept my answer if it was useful. http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @ross999 But $\pi/2$ is a solution. Re-check your work.

Comment: @RobertZ $ \frac{\pi}{6} < arg Z \le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @ross999 Yes, That's right!